# I'm in the uk, I wish to purchase bitcoins, but the process seems to be very convoluted. There has to be an easy way?

Tags: payment

Any way that doesn't involve days of delay, verification etc? Are private traders available?

Answer (score 3):

Provided there is someone near you who advertises on [LocalBitcoins](http://localbitcoins.com), it's probably the most effortless solution available at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

We offer 3 deposit methods for UK users:

Faster Payments - https://blockchain.info/wallet/deposit-bank-transfer

PingIt - https://blockchain.info/wallet/deposit-pingit

Sofort Banking - https://blockchain.info/wallet/deposit-sofort-banking

Comment: This no longer works

Answer (score 0):

[Localbitcoins.com](http://Localbitcoins.com) is best for bank transfers now. You don't need to live near the seller, just have an account in GBP to transfer £ to the seller's account. You can search for all sellers within X miles of a city near the middle of the UK.

However be careful, since the [Localbitcoins.com](http://Localbitcoins.com) system isn't designed for bank transfers. Review the profiles carefully if you use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

http://quickbitcoin.co.uk

https://bitbargain.co.uk/

Both work fine.